# What does "have adequate means of subsistence" mean for Austrian residency over three months?

Tags: eu-citizens, residency, austria

I am a dual Hungarian-Canadian citizen and a Canadian resident and once this covid madness is over I would like to spend more than three months in Austria. I was looking at https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/12/Seite.120225.html and it says

> they have sufficient means of life and sufficient health insurance coverage for themselves

well, what is that? The german version https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/themen/leben_in_oesterreich/aufenthalt/4/Seite.120210.html is not much more helpful. How much money are they looking for daily/monthly and what sort of health insurance?

Comment: Adequate means of subsistence means enough “not to become a burden on the social assistance system of the host Member State” (article 7(1)(b) of directive 2004/38), i.e. above the threshold to qualify for whatever basic welfare benefits exist there. I will see if I can find more details on how that's implemented in Austria to provide an answer. Typically, it would be a yearly income or wealth threshold rather than a *per diem* based on actual costs of living. I don't know how “comprehensive sickness insurance cover” is defined.

Comment: How much longer than 3 months do you want to spend in Austria?  My parents routinely spent four to five months in France without worrying about this (my father was a Dutch/US dual citizen).  The Austrian implementation may of course be such that you might actually be fined if you try something like that, but in France the "fine" is imposed by a late application for a residence card carrying a higher fee.  If you leave without applying, there is effectively no consequence.  And that's for the third-country family member, not the EU citizen.